# Why is this edit request rejected?

Tags: discussion

[Link to suggested edit](https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/71340). I described the facts available as to what the disease is and what it can do.

The edit was rejected by Dimitri mx with a reason "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer."

I do not understand this reason, because this is in no way a comment (I clarify the question, not ask the author of the post for clarification), and it is in no way an answer either. Can someone explain?

Comment: I saw this edit, and at first, I thought it was *an attempt* at answering the question, even if it's a partial answer (the disease's description but not knowing the name). I decided to skip it though because I'm not sure whether I should accept or reject it.

Comment: Since there's no response from Dimitri mx, I'm going to send the edit request again, this time with more details.